# How to convert a "raw" DOM Event to a React SyntheticEvent?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I use two libraries, one library which emits "raw" DOM events (lib.dom.d.ts), and one other library which consumes `React.SyntheticEvents`.

What is the best way to **cleanly** transform the raw event into a SyntheticEvent?

Comment: I believe the best thing to do is to dispatch the events to the popover component. This way you won't have to worry passing/converting and getting the events to reach the component.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a direct answer, but it's too long to comment.

I don't think it is a good practice of trying to wrap/convert a DOM event to a `React.SyntheticEvent`. And I can't see there is a user case of rendering with non-React but responding the events with React. Perhaps you need to consider choosing another consumption library. Simply speaking, no direct way to construct a `SyntheticEvent` from a DOM event.

From https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html `SyntheticEvent` is a high level API of wrapping the basic DOM event. The goal of wrapping the basic DOM event with some logic is having the events working identically cross-browser.

Although from
https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/993ca533b42756811731f6b7791ae06a35ee6b4d/packages/react-dom/src/events/plugins/SelectEventPlugin.js or https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/9198a5cec0936a21a5ba194a22fcbac03eba5d1d/packages/react-dom/src/events/plugins/ChangeEventPlugin.js
, you can find some clue of how to construct a `SyntheticEvent`, the work is not only constructing the `SyntheticEven`, but also other logic React has done and which your consumption library relies. If you construct a `SyntheticEvent` by yourself, then you also need to write the logic to meet the expectation.

Comment: The use case is rather straight-forward: The event producer lib uses native js (d3) add DOM MouseEvents and exposes these as callbacks. The event consumer lib is a react popover component (material-ui popover) that should be displayed. Although I agree that I should replace either the producing or the consuming lib to get rid of the problem, sometimes this is not possible (due to constraints), so I bet I am not alone with this problem.

Comment: If you can give a demo here, I belive there should be more ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You can consume "raw" DOM event in your component and emit new event which will be consumed by other library.